# Python Scrapy get select

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I hope someone can help me here. I want to use Scrappy to extract different links from a select list. Unfortunately I can't find the right command.

This is the HTML Code:

```
    <div class="testclass">
                        <div id="loading_page" class="_loading_page" style="display:none;">
      <span id="Message"></span>
      <img src="/test.gif" style="align: center; vertical-align: middle">
   </div>

    <select name="test" id="variant" class="input-block note" style="">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Which Link</option>
        <option value="A" data-varianturl="Link1"> Link A</option>
                <option value="B" data-varianturl="Link2"> Link B</option>
                                </select>
```

For example, I have tried it with:

```
url = response.css('testclass > select::attr(test)').extract_first()
```

But unfortunately I don't get the links.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: try response.css('#variant > option:nth-child(2)').extract_first()

Comment: Thanks gherkim: when I use this I get this respons: '<option value="A" data-varianturl="Link A"> Link A</option>' but I need only the data-varianturl

Comment: Ok I got it. With an ::attr(data-varianturl ) I get the Link. Thank you gherkim. :)